# Exporting an object as svg from inkscape

Tags: inkscape, export, svg

I know that Inkscape does not have the ability to export selected objects as svg, but is there a workaround that people have found that works?

Comment: Just shooting from the hip but wouldn't Copy, new Document, Paste, Save work?

Comment: I was almost sure one could do that with the command-line option. There is indeed an export-plain-svg option, but it does not respect the export-id :'(

Comment: I don't have enough rep here to answer, but I wrote a script to batch export Inkscape layers into separate SVG - you could put each of your objects on a different layer. The script is here: https://github.com/splitbrain/material-icons

Comment: Alas, the link 404s   :-(

Answer (score 162, accepted):

A straight-forward method is the following:

1. Select the object(s) to export.
2. "Resize to content" (File → Document Properties) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
3. "Invert selection" (Edit → Invert selection) or <kbd>!</kbd>, and <kbd>Del</kbd> all other objects.
4. "Save As" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
5. Select Optimized SVG as the format if you want to use it on the web.

Not as quick as I would like but quicker than creating a new document for each graphic that you want to export.

Comment: This does not work. Inkscape 0.92.4 just shows popup "File %filename% could not be saved" even when trying to save a black document.

Comment: @user7860670 Which step didn't work for you? It works for me. But anyway, it's quite inconvenient that after these years, there's still no built-in Export Selection option in INkscape.

Answer (score 34):

I keep another instance of Inkscape running on the side and just copy-paste the object I want to save into the scratch document, then `save`.

Another option if you just want the path data is to select the object, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open the XML editor, grab the pieces you want (usually the `d` attribute), then paste to wherever.

Answer (score 6):

As of Inkscape 1.2+ there is now a native way to batch export multiple objects to SVG, or any other supported export format for that matter.

You can do this from the regular *File > Export* dialog. In the *Batch* tab you can export either *Layers*, *Selection*, or *Pages*.

[image]

Using the *Object Properties* dialog <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>O</kbd>, add an *ID* or *Label* to your assets that will be used to determine their file name when exporting.

[image]

Set up all objects you want to export into an organization method that best suits your needs. If they are composed of separate elements, you can either bundle them into separate groups, place each set into a dedicated layer, or set up one individual page for each element, one per desired exported file.

[image]

You can even batch export to multiple file formats simultaneously, by pressing the *Add* button and choosing different extensions.

[image]

It allows choosing any file format available in for saving, including vector ones. To take full advantage of this functionality you may have to enable it in *Edit > Preferences > Input/Output > Show all outputs in Export Dialog*.

[image]

Comment: A nice update. Thanks for sharing +1